# Clone non-null fields only

Tags: java

How would you "clone" a Java Object and only cloning non-null fields?

Consider this code:

```java
MyObject original = getObject(); 
MyObject copyOfNonNullFields = copy(original, MyObject.lass);
```

As such it would work in any arbitrary Java object. I've checked Dozer http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ but it needs custom XML mapping for each object class to copy.

Comment: How about https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo

Comment: The only way I see to do this in a generic way would be through reflection. The real question is: why do you need this capability? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).